# Overriding y axis minimum displays several duplicate labels and creates display glitches

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

When I override the y axis' minimum, it will duplicate several labels. Also, it creates a display glitch on the x axis too.

Essentially, if I remove line 42, the graph will display properly:

```
var axis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SPCT");
//axis.overrideMin = 0.9;
```

Example http://pastebin.com/RQLfAduC

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measure axis - limit tick values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585769/measure-axis-limit-tick-values)

Comment: @JohnKiernander That did the trick... will you be posting an answer? Essentially, it changing from measure axis to category axis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line

`var axis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SPCT");`

to

`var axis = myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "SPCT");`