# Dimple plotting aggregated values data which is wrong

Tags: dimple.js

I have code like below.  I have attached 2 screenhots where in issue is clear. I just want Y-axis data to be hardcoded like 5,10,15,20,25 and data to be represented correctly in graph.

Trail 1: If i use addAxis for Y
1. Data shows properly
2. But y Axis ticks are not as required.

Trail 2: If i add addCategoryAxis for Y
1. Data does not show up properly
2. y Axis ticks are not as required. I need 5 interval between each ticks.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Am i missing anything?

[image]

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<div id="chartContainer">
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 800, 400);

      var data = [
    {
        "Type": "Type1",
        "Range": 128000,
        "Price": 20
    },
    {
        "Type": "Type1",
        "Range": 128000,
        "Price": 18
    },
    {
        "Type": "Type1",
        "Range": 145000,
        "Price": 21
    },
    {
        "Type": "Type2",
        "Range": 129000,
        "Price": 20
    },
    {
        "Type": "Type2",
        "Range": 145000,
        "Price": 21
    },
    {
        "Type": "Type2",
        "Range": 195000,
        "Price": 17
    }
];

      var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      chart.setBounds(60,20,680,330);
      var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Range");
      var y1 = chart.addAxis("y", "Price");
      y1.ticks = 5;

      var lines = chart.addSeries("Type", dimple.plot.line, [x,y1]);
      lines.lineMarkers = true;
      x.addOrderRule("Tyre");
      chart.addLegend(60, 5, 680, 10, "right", lines);
      chart.draw();



  </script>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: @john-kiernander - Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`tickValues` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues)?

You can use it to specify exact values for the ticks:

```
yAxis.tickValues(d3.range(0, 25, 5));
```

Comment: I get error like TypeError: y1.tickValues is not a function

Comment: I missed the fact that you're using dimple.js. 
Apparently changing the tickValues is somehow limited in dimple.js. Maybe this can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585769/measure-axis-limit-tick-values